# MS Access Table shown in query as Alias

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query in a database that refrences a table called `%$##@_Alias`

How can I tell where the query is getting its data?

I am getting no intelligent answers when searching the web for this.

UPDATE:
I looked at the SQL View of the query and got this:

```
SELECT [%$##@_Alias].F87 AS ID_PEERGROUP, [%$##@_Alias].F1 AS FUNDNAME, [%$##@_Alias].F2 AS ISIN, [%$##@_Alias].F82 AS SECID, [%$##@_Alias].F4 AS NAV, [%$##@_Alias].F6 AS CCY, IIf(Not IsNull([F7]),CDbl([F7])/1000000,IIf(Not IsNull([F8]),CDbl([F8])/1000000,IIf(Not IsNull([F9]),CDbl([F9])/1000000,IIf(Not IsNull([F10]),CDbl([F10])/1000000,-1)))) AS LC_FUNDSIZE, [%$##@_Alias].F81 AS COUNTRYLIST, [%$##@_Alias].F63 AS PRIMARY_FLAG, [%$##@_Alias].F77 AS TAX, [%$##@_Alias].F84 AS BENCHMARK_MPT, [%$##@_Alias].F85 AS DISTRIBUTION_STATUS, [%$##@_Alias].F86 AS VALOR, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Austria")<>0,True,False) AS REG_AT, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Belgium")<>0,True,False) AS REG_BE, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"France")<>0,True,False) AS REG_FR, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Hong Kong")<>0,True,False) AS REG_HK, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Italy")<>0,True,False) AS REG_IT, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Luxembourg")<>0,True,False) AS REG_LU, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Netherlands")<>0,True,False) AS REG_NL, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Poland")<>0,True,False) AS REG_PL, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Singapore")<>0,True,False) AS REG_SG, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Spain")<>0,True,False) AS REG_ES, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Switzerland")<>0,True,False) AS REG_CH, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Emirates")<>0,True,False) AS REG_UE, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"Germany")<>0,True,False) AS REG_DE, IIf(InStr(1,[%$##@_Alias].[F81],"United Kingdom")<>0,True,False) AS REG_UK, [%$##@_Alias].F76 AS P_Perf3Y_G, [%$##@_Alias].F78 AS P_PerfYTD_G, [%$##@_Alias].F31 AS R_Vola3Y_K_USD, False AS isSarasin, 1 AS Sectype, tbl_Currency.Currency_ISO, [%$##@_Alias].F88 AS Repliation_Method, [%$##@_Alias].F89 AS TER, [%$##@_Alias].F90 AS Inception_Date, [%$##@_Alias].F91 AS Broad_Category, Right([F3],Len([F3])-8) AS Peergroup, [%$##@_Alias].F93 AS Spread
FROM tbl_Currency RIGHT JOIN (select * from
[ETF Transfer - HEADER]

UNION ALL select * from
(
select * from
[ETF Transfer]

)
)  AS [%$##@_Alias] ON tbl_Currency.Currency_Name = [%$##@_Alias].F6
WHERE ((([%$##@_Alias].F2)<>"" And ([%$##@_Alias].F2)<>"ISIN" And ([%$##@_Alias].F2)<>'ABC'));
```

Comment: open the query in design view and switch to SQL view. Then examine the `FROM` clause

Comment: I added the SQL View code. I actually already looked at it, but only saw the same non-existent table referenced

Comment: You didn't assign an alias to the subquery, so Access used `%$##@_Alias` as the alias.  Replace `%$##@_Alias` with your own alias ... perhaps `MySubquery`

Comment: In this case the subquery can be replaced by the table itself, since it's just a `select * from`

Comment: @hansup Thank you for your help! Now that I understand it, I can look into this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously an `Alias` for `select * from [ETF Transfer]`. To remove this Alias:

- open the query in Design view,
- Make sure the Properties window is visible
- click on the `%$##@_Alias` "table"
- in the Alias property, type [ETF Transfer], then press `Enter`

Done... Alias should be gone